# Country and State dropdowns in angular 2

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, npm

I have two dropdowns (`<select>` tags) in my form, for country and state. When the user selects a country, the state field should get auto-populated with the corresponding values. It's a common enough UI element.

I tried to find an npm package that helps me. Found [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-region-selector) called **country-region-selector** and followed the instructions, but wasn't able to get it to work in angular. Specifically, I added the elements and added the required class and other attributes to them. The query by class even fetches the desired element, but it's not populated.

Does anyone know of any alternative npm package or a script that's proven to work with Angular2, or am I better of hand-coding this, in a way shown [here](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/09/dynamic-country-state-javascript-menu-example/).

Comment: try this: http://embed.plnkr.co/cuMsdkK6SuTn41uQSeI6

Answer (score 2):

country.ts file

```
export class Country {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) { }
}
```

countrylistcomponent.html

```
    <label>Country:</label> 
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry.id" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="#country of countries" value= {{country.id}}>{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<div>
<label>State:</label>
<select>
  <option *ngIf='selectedCountry.id == 0' value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="#state of states " value= {{state.id}}>{{state.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

countrylistcomponent.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { DataService } from './dataservice';
import { Country } from './country';
import { State } from './state';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-country-list',
  templateUrl: 'app/countrylistcomponent.html',
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class CountryListComponent {
  selectedCountry:Country = new Country(0, 'India'); 
  countries: Country[];
  states: State[];

  constructor(private _dataService: DataService) {
    this.countries = this._dataService.getCountries();
  }

  onSelect(countryid) {
    this.states = this._dataService.getStates().filter((item)=> item.countryid == countryid);
  }
}
```

dataservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Country } from './country';
import { State } from './state';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  getCountries() {
    return [
     new Country(1, 'USA' ),
     new Country(2, 'India' ),
     new Country(3, 'Australia' )
    ];
  }

  getStates() {
   return [
     new State(1, 1, 'Arizona' ),
     new State(2, 1, 'Alaska' ),
     new State(3, 1, 'Florida'),
     new State(4, 1, 'Hawaii'),
     new State(5, 2, 'Gujarat' ),
     new State(6, 2, 'Goa'),
     new State(7, 2, 'Punjab' ),
     new State(8, 3, 'Queensland' ),
     new State(9, 3, 'South Australia' ),
     new State(10, 3, 'Tasmania')
    ];
  }
}
```

state.ts

```
export class State {
  constructor(public id: number, public countryid: int, public name: string) { }
}
```

go to plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/cuMsdkK6SuTn41uQSeI6